# How to turn on a LED with specific address on dot-matrix 74HC595?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, led, circuit

I have problem when want to determine the address for each LED in dot-matrix 8x8 74HC595, im trying to light on only 1 LED specifically with the address. i have tried many tutorial and documentation but still no luck to light on only 1 LED with spesific location.

this is my circuit design : 
https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/Super_Kit_V2_for_RaspberryPi/lesson-12-driving-dot-matrix-by-74hc595-super-kit-for-raspberrypi.html

my code with C:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define   SDI   0   //serial data input
#define   RCLK  1   //memory clock input
#define   SRCLK 2   //shift register clock input

unsigned char LED[8] ={0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

void pulse(int pin)
{
    digitalWrite(pin, 0);
    digitalWrite(pin, 1);
}

void ShiftOUT(unsigned char byte)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        // char a = byte & (0x80 >> i)) > 0;
        digitalWrite(SDI, (( byte & (0x80 >> i)) > 0));
        printf("%d", (( byte >> i > 0)));
        pulse(SRCLK);
    }


    printf("\n","==================");
}

void init(void)
{
    pinMode(SDI, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RCLK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SRCLK, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(SDI, 0);
    digitalWrite(RCLK, 0);
    digitalWrite(SRCLK, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    if(wiringPiSetup() == -1)
    {
        printf("setup wiringPi failed !");
        return 1;
    }

    init();

    while(1)
    {
         for(i=0;i<8;i++)
         {

            ShiftOUT(LED[i]);
            pulse(RCLK);
            // printf("=======pull latch========");
            // printf("\n");
            delay(150);
         }


        delay(500);


   }

    return 0;
}
```

This code i tried will light on 1 row,i want to light on 1 LED with spesific location

Here is the link i use for simulation to addressing the LED : https://www.riyas.org/2013/12/online-led-matrix-font-generator-with.html

Any help?Thank you

Comment: Aren't you missing a delay() or sleep() in function pulse()?

Comment: To turn on 1 led, col must be 0 and row must be 1. So, if you want to turn on led (1, 0), row[7-0] = 0x02, col[7-0] = 0xfe. You need shift 2 byte for 2 74hc595 IC: row[7-0] andd col[7-0]

Comment: No,I follow the tutorial no delay or sleep in pulse function,but why should i put delay?

Comment: @Programmerdude if the matrix is (1,0) means row[7-0] = 0x02, col[7-0] = 0xfe , i dont understand this part,why col[7-0] is 0xfe.I tried on  https://www.riyas.org/2013/12/online-led-matrix-font-generator-with.html for matrix (1,0) is 0x02,sorry im new with this thing can you explain more

Comment: As i said above, to turn on 1 led, col must be 0 and row must be 1. row[7-0] = 0x02 = 0b00000010, bit 1 of row is 1 and other is 0. col[7-0] = 0xfe = 0x11111110, bit 0 of col is 0 and other is 1. Only led (1, 0) is turned on.

Comment: @Programmerdude So , if i want (2,1) means row[7-0] = 00000100 and col[7-0] = 11111101,is that right?then what shift 2 bytes means?

Comment: yes, row[7-0] = 00000100 and col[7-0] = 11111101. In [your circuit design](https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/Super_Kit_V2_for_RaspberryPi/lesson-12-driving-dot-matrix-by-74hc595-super-kit-for-raspberrypi.html), there are 2 74hc595 IC for manage row and col of led matrix so you need 2 byte, 1 byte for row and 1 byte for col.

Comment: I think in https://www.riyas.org/2013/12/online-led-matrix-font-generator-with.html, their circuit is different, row pin always is high (logic 1) so you only need set col.

Comment: @Programmerdude oh i see,so do i still need my shiftOut function and put (row[7-0],col[7-0] ) as parameter? In my shiftOut function i still dont understand why need loop and shiftleft (( byte & (0x80 >> i)) > 0) stand for?

Comment: shiftOut function will shift 1 byte (8bit) so you can call shiftOut twice.

Comment: ( byte & (0x80 >> i)) > 0 will return 0 or 1: 0 if bit i-th of byte is 0 andd 1 if bit i-th of byte is 1. The loop will shift all 8 bit of byte.

Comment: @Programmerdude can you explain why need to shift?and why must have 0x80?

Comment: If you want to more detail, you can read [74HC595 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf). You can only shift out 1 bit at a time so you need 8 time (loop) for shift out 8 bit. 0x80 = 0b10000000, 0x80 >> 1 = 0b01000000, ... Any problem?

Comment: @Programmerdude Okay thank you so much for your help

Comment: you are welcome